# How to build Install or Impala without cloudera

Tags: cmake, build, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, impala

Since past many days. I am trying to install apache impala in our on premise server(Dont have cloudera or dont have any plan to get cloudera).
I have a VM with following OS.

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.9 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.9"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 (Maipo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.9:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.9
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.9"
```

Inorder to avoid automatic library updates which may break existing functionality. I have created a redhat docker container. Inside that container i have downloaded the impala tar from official site. [officialsite](https://impala.apache.org/downloads.html). According to the build instruction i am running buildall.sh in root folder of project and it is giving me maven not found error.

```
which: no javac in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin)
IMPALA_VERSION          = 4.1.1-RELEASE
IMPALA_HOME             = /impala
HADOOP_HOME             = /impala/toolchain/cdp_components-23144489/hadoop-3.1.1.7.2.15.0-88/
HADOOP_CONF_DIR         = /impala/fe/src/test/resources
HADOOP_INCLUDE_DIR      = /impala/toolchain/cdp_components-23144489/hadoop-3.1.1.7.2.15.0-88//include
HADOOP_LIB_DIR          = /impala/toolchain/cdp_components-23144489/hadoop-3.1.1.7.2.15.0-88//lib
IMPALA_CLUSTER_NODES_DIR= /impala/testdata/cluster/cdh7
HIVE_HOME               = /impala/toolchain/cdp_components-23144489/apache-hive-3.1.3000.7.2.15.0-88-bin
HIVE_CONF_DIR           = /impala/fe/./src/test/resources
HIVE_SRC_DIR            = /impala/toolchain/cdp_components-23144489/hive-3.1.3000.7.2.15.0-88
HBASE_HOME              = /impala/toolchain/cdp_components-23144489/hbase-2.4.6.7.2.15.0-88/
HBASE_CONF_DIR          = /impala/fe/src/test/resources
RANGER_HOME             = /impala/toolchain/cdp_components-23144489/ranger-2.1.0.7.2.15.0-88-admin
RANGER_CONF_DIR         = /impala/fe/src/test/resources
THRIFT_HOME             = /impala/toolchain/toolchain-packages-gcc7.5.0/thrift-0.11.0-p5
CLASSPATH               = /impala/fe/src/test/resources:/impala/fe/target/classes:/impala/fe/target/dependency:
LIBHDFS_OPTS            =  -Djava.library.path=/impala/toolchain/cdp_components-23144489/hadoop-3.1.1.7.2.15.0-88//lib/native/ -XX:ErrorFile=/impala/logs/hs_err_pid%p.log -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
JAVA_HOME               = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
POSTGRES_JDBC_DRIVER    = /impala/fe/target/dependency/postgresql-42.3.3.jar
IMPALA_TOOLCHAIN        = /impala/toolchain
IMPALA_TOOLCHAIN_PACKAGES_HOME = /impala/toolchain/toolchain-packages-gcc7.5.0
METASTORE_DB            = HMS_impala_cdp
DOWNLOAD_CDH_COMPONENTS = true
IMPALA_MAVEN_OPTIONS    =
IMPALA_TOOLCHAIN_HOST   = native-toolchain.s3.amazonaws.com
CDP_BUILD_NUMBER        = 23144489
CDP_COMPONENTS_HOME     = /impala/toolchain/cdp_components-23144489
IMPALA_HADOOP_VERSION   = 3.1.1.7.2.15.0-88
IMPALA_AVRO_JAVA_VERSION= 1.8.2.7.2.15.0-88
IMPALA_PARQUET_VERSION  = 1.10.99.7.2.15.0-88
IMPALA_HIVE_VERSION     = 3.1.3000.7.2.15.0-88
IMPALA_HBASE_VERSION    = 2.4.6.7.2.15.0-88
IMPALA_HUDI_VERSION     = 0.5.0-incubating
IMPALA_KUDU_VERSION     = 1.16.0
IMPALA_RANGER_VERSION   = 2.1.0.7.2.15.0-88
IMPALA_ICEBERG_VERSION  = 0.9.1.7.2.15.0-88
IMPALA_GCS_VERSION      = 2.1.2.7.2.15.0-88
IMPALA_COS_VERSION      = 3.1.0-5.9.3
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
/impala/java/ext-data-source /impala
========================================================================
Running mvn  clean
Directory /impala/java/ext-data-source
========================================================================
/impala/bin/mvn-quiet.sh: line 43: mvn: command not found
mvn  clean exited with code 0
ERROR in /impala/bin/clean.sh at line 35: ${IMPALA_HOME}/bin/mvn-quiet.sh clean
Generated: /impala/logs/extra_junit_xml_logs/generate_junitxml.buildall.clean.20230517_09_39_18.xml
ERROR in ./buildall.sh at line 617: "$IMPALA_HOME/bin/clean.sh"
Generated: /impala/logs/extra_junit_xml_logs/generate_junitxml.buildall.buildall.20230517_09_39_18.xml
```

Also the /impala/toolchain folder is also not present. I cloned [cloudera/native-toolchain](https://github.com/cloudera/native-toolchain) repo and according to its build instruction i ran buildall.sh it is giving me this error

```
[root@0cc0310d8e60 toolchain]# ./buildall.sh
++ : generic
++ : generic
++ export BUILD_LABEL
++ set +x
Build ID is a28ef0ef-77ff-4a07-8fe9-ece79924f0d1-93f89038db
Warning: Unable to detect operating system
USE_CCACHE was enabled but ccache is not in PATH
```

Here i can see that mvn and ccache is missing even if i install them one and another errors are comming this is my 7th attempt. Can some one provide me any related resources to build impala or to get prebuilt impala. I am new to building things from source if and not able to get deep sense of makefiles and mvn and its usages. So other related material will also be appreciated.