# How to build impala without any platform dependencies and with build fit in single folder which can be migrated to other machines as well

Tags: cloudera, impala, cloudera-cdh

Since past few months. I am trying to build latest impala version 4.1.1. I am facing various issues. I don't even remember now. Some common issues includes .so file for glibc version conflicts and so. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76415845/problem-running-impalad-libc-so-6-working-in-centos-7-but-not-in-rhel-7) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76270763/how-to-build-install-or-impala-without-cloudera). In this cases impalad it self was not starting. When i used all the things of cloudera .I was able to build it but facing some java class not found issues. I tried to add all class paths and set all the ld-library-paths. In one case i was able to start impala in one vm but when i migrated that build to another machine it again started giving library issues and such.

I am not able to find any proper guide to build it. Not sure whether cloudera has purposefully done it or not. Even some scripts only supports apt not yum. Some where paths are not proper of the script which needs to be called. I want impala to be built and pack in one folder. Which is platform independent and easy migratable and usable. Any suggestion and hint is very much appreciable. Thanks in Advance.